# .htaccess Redirect not working RewriteRule 301

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following to add www to the beginning of the URL, and then remove any trailing slash.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

I then have the following to redirect the URL:

```
RewriteRule ^url-1/$ /url-2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

I then have a RewriteRule on `/url-2` like:

```
RewriteRule ^url-2/$ index.php?view=url2 [QSA,L]
```

However, this doesnt redirect from url-1 to url-2

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the issue to this myself. I had since implemented the redirect that removes the trailing slash. My RewriteRules contained the trailing slash, so removing these worked.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^url-1$ /url-2 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^url-2$ index.php?view=url2 [QSA,L]
```